# React Native: fixed height Lists in NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using NativeBase's `List` component to dynamically render data.
This is my JSX structure:

```
<Container>
 <Content>
  //some components here
  <List />
   <List />
   <List />
 //some components here
 </Content>
 </Container>
 //whole container,content is scrollable
```

I want the `List` components to be of fixed height, say `500`. But I want the overflow data to be scrollable inside this fixed height *window*.

Example `List`:

```
 <List
        dataArray={this.state.data}
        renderRow={item =>
          <ListItem>
            {this.formatted(item)}
          </ListItem>}
      />
```

I've tried setting style to `List` directly , wrapping it in `Container`/`Content`/`View`/`ScrollView` to no avail.

Comment: try <View style={height: 50} ><List/> <View>

Comment: you can try reaplace NativeBase "Container" component by React Native "View" component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567986/set-height-of-listview-in-react-native